# Is there a way to display a view by date?

Tags: python, django

Like if i want paragraph to be on monday. Another paragraph on tuesday, Wednesday and whole week. Please help to advice me place to get informantion! Thank you.

Comment: Will you have a different page for every day of the week? Or is it one page and there are different paragraphs for each day of the week? Is the paragraph stored in the database?

Comment: It’s all in one page. I just want to know is there a way to do that? Like select by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dynamic view based on the day of the week is possible, for example:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def my_view(request):
    weekday = timezone.now().weekday()
    if weekday == 0:
       paragraph = "Happy Monday!"
    elif weekday == 1:
       paragraph = "Happy Tuesday!"
    ...
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'paragraph': paragraph}
```

You could also store the paragraphs in a model and access them through a query.

Comment: If i want it on a html is can just call it by {{ paragraph }} ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following what you mean by, "view."  Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
4
>>> view = ["Monday Message", "Tuesday Message", "Wednesday Message", "Thursday Message",
        "Friday Message", "Saturday Message", "Sunday Message", "Week Message"]
>>> print("Today's View: {}".format(view[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()]))
Today's View: Friday Message
```

Answer (score 0):

1. regexp on url
2. route in view by the requested url to a certain path